# What step handles setting the url hostname when uploading an Ionic Capacitor project to TestFlight?

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, capacitor

I am uploading my Ionic Capacitor app to TestFlight using a paid developer account and it continues to be configured to use the localhost hostname for the URL.

I have tried a plethora of commands for building the project out to XCode.

`ionic capacitor run ios --external --prod`

```
ionic build
ionic cap sync
ionic cap copy
```

`ionic capacitor build ios --prod`

I am still learning the process, is it supposed to run on localhost when you use TestFlight?

This is the capacitor.config.ts file:

```
import { CapacitorConfig } from "@capacitor/cli";

const config: CapacitorConfig = {
  appId: "com.traineraid",
  appName: "Traineraid",
  webDir: "build",
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  server: {},
};

export default config;
```

One of the main reasons I am having difficulty is the I have firebase emulators set up that run instead of the production server when using a localhost URL, so when open the app using TestFlight on my phone, it warns me it is trying to use the emulators, which I don't have running, and it obviously can't work.

Is there a step of piece that is missing from this that is causing these problems? Or is this how it actually is supposed to operate and the code is what needs to change?

Answer (score 2):

Capacitor apps ship with the app files bundled inside the app, so there is no “production server”, all the files are local.

Capacitor serves the local files from `capacitor://localhost` on iOS and `http://localhost` on Android, because you need an url to load in the app, but the url doesn’t really matter much.

When you run `ionic capacitor run ios --external --prod` it uses a local dev web server, but that’s just to allow live reload and making development easier, but for publishing the app you don’t need a server. Just run `ionic build` and then `npx cap copy` and all the files will be copied to the app bundle.